# Message: 'ActiveXOjbect' is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/tr/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang = "en" lang = "en">
    <head>
        <title>Finding Element Values in an XML Document</title>

        <script language = "javascript" type = "text/javascript">
            function getStudentData(){
                var xmlDoc;
                xmlDoc = new ActiveXOjbect("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                xmlDoc.load("School.xml");

                nodeSchool = xmlDoc.documentElement;
                nodeClass = nodeSchool.firstChild;
                nodeStudents = nodeClass.lastChild;
                nodeStudent = nodeStudents.lastChild;
                nodeFirstName = nodeStudent.firstChild;
                nodeLastName = nodeFirstName.nextSibling;

                outputMessage = "Name: " + nodeFirstName.firstChild.nodeValue + " " + nodeLastName.firstChild.nodeValue;
                message.innerHTML = outputMessage;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <center>
            <h1>Finding Element Values in an XML Document</h1>

            <div id = "message"></div>
            <p>
                <input type = "button" value = "Get Second Student's Name" onClick = "getStudentData()" />
            </p>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

and it gives error like this

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1;
>   Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR
>   3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2) Timestamp: Fri, 11 Jan 2013 14:33:05 UTC
>
> Message: 'ActiveXOjbect' is undefined Line: 19 Char: 5 Code: 0 URI:
>   file:///D:/Priyal/Personal/Programing/XHTML/XML/School.html
>
> Message: 'ActiveXOjbect' is undefined Line: 19 Char: 5 Code: 0 URI:
>   file:///D:/Priyal/Personal/Programing/XHTML/XML/School.html

Comment: please advice what you mean from it.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You have a typo.

Replace `ActiveXOjbect` with `ActiveXObject`.

But you should also note that `ActiveXObject` is available **only** in Internet Explorer. All other browsers will throw the same error.

Comment: so it would be better to use a xml-reader plugin?

Comment: @Vogel612 It would be better to use jQuery for that :) It can load and parse XML documents.